# Can anyone identify this Twin-Lens Reflex 1940(ish) camera?

Tags: equipment-identification, zeiss, camera-identification, twin-lens-reflex

The photo was probably taken in the 40s, and the photographer was relatively well off. Can anyone identify the this specific camera (and flash if it's not permanently attached)?

Medium format Rolleiflex, Voigtlander, Reflekta, Aires Automat, Kinaflex and Rolleicord look similar but not the same. Wonder if anyone might know, or the best place to search? Currently reverse image engineering in search engines and searching for popular cameras around that time frame and scrolling endlessly, but so far no luck.

[image: Photo]

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, try the classic camera forum on photo.net. Some of the people there are amazing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It appears to be a [Zeiss Ikon Ikoflex I (850/16)](http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Zeiss_Ikon_Ikoflex_II).

[image: Zeiss Ikon Ikoflex I (850/16), from camera-wiki.org]
<sup>[*Zeiss Ikon Ikoflex I (850/16)*](https://www.flickr.com/photos/alf_sigaro/8250109516/in/pool-camerawiki/), by [Alf Sigaro](http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Category:Image_by_Alf_Sigaro). Creative Commons [BY-NC-ND 2.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/2.0/)</sup>

The key details that seem to match are:

- rectangular silver trim around the front
- flash sync terminal at bottom corner
- wide silver name plate surrounded by screws
- shallow miter/beveled focusing screen cover

Note that the your photo was taken in a mirror, so the camera is reversed.

> and flash if it's not permanently attached

If you're talking about the box on top, it's not a flash. It's the unfolded top cover for the focusing screen. You used to look down onto the focusing screen on TLRs (and even several SLRs that had removable viewfinders) in order to focus. Here's a different view of the open focusing screen cover of a slightly older Ikoflex 1a:

[image: Zeiss Ikon Ikofle 1a, open focusing screen]
<sup>[*ZEISS IKON - Ikoflex IA , 1953, lens Tessar "T", 1:3.5 ƒ=7.5cm*](https://www.flickr.com/photos/132420193@N06/16957838577), by [Luis Cozeto](https://www.flickr.com/photos/132420193@N06/). Creative Commons [BY 2.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/)</sup>

Comment: Oh my gosh, you're amazing! I've been scouring Google for 2 nights and kept finding items close but no cigar, and the above on initial inspection seems to be a perfect match. So thankful!!!!